# If $f$ has a vanishing (first or higher) derivative at every point, $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

There's a problem from calculus I remember:
$$\forall x\ \exists n.\ f^{(n)}(x) = 0 \iff \exists n\ \forall x.\ f^{(n)}(x) = 0\,.$$

Function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, and the notation $f^{(n)}$ means differentiation.

Right side is just curious statement that $f$ is a polynomial. Of course $(\Leftarrow)$ is just trivial, however, $(\Rightarrow)$ is far from obvious.
Have anybody seen this, maybe somebody knows where it comes from? What about the proof of $(\Rightarrow)$?

Comment: I've seen it once on the forum http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/. We have to use the Baire category theorem. But I forgot the proof.

Comment: oh yeah, it's here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51581/an-application-of-baire-category-theorem :D

Comment: See also my posting in https://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/8963982857bc5f31?hl=en

Comment: The version on MO closest to this question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some reference about the problem:

- [this thread at Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial);
- [Robert Israel's solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/sci.math/UbNUvB3uGvE/MV-8VyiYY4kJ).